# MS SQL High IO/cost

Tags: sql-server, performance, io

I have a table with over 40m records, and i found the read from this table incredible slow.
The table itself has around 70 columns, and most of them have normal data type, like nvarchar(20) int,bit, etc.. I have only a few with nvarchar(1000) and nvarchar(4000) like 3-5 of them.

If I perform a select top1 row i see my IO cost is over 2000
[image]
When i want to select everything from the table, that takes more than an hour without any transform.
Is that normal? Is there any way to improve it?

if i could lower my Io cost, then maybe it could increase my performance.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to select all 70 columns and 40 million rows in a single query though? That is not a reasonable query. Instead, try to figure out why you actual queries are running slow. Though having so many large nvarchar columns is always going to affect performance.

Comment: Notice the "operator cost" which is combined CPU + IO is only `0.0032831`. The IO cost you have underlined is the cost for doing an entire scan of all rows. The row goal effect of `TOP 1` adjusts the operator costs but not the I/O Cost and CPU Cost - these still display the pre-adjusted costs. So SQL Server isn't really telling you that selecting a single row will cost 2816 optimiser beans

Answer (score 0):

Each nvarchar(4000) can use up to 8 000 bytes. 8kb is one page... So potentially with 5 columns of nvarchar(4000) can potentially read 5 pages... 70 columns with nvarchar(20) is 2 800 bytes. The result is that one row can use 6 pages...

40m rows (not record... that is a cobol term) will use a maximum of 40 000 000 x 6 pages, = 240 m pages...

Consider yourself happy that your query just cost 2816 in terms of IO just with an obese table....

Don't you think the design of your table respects all the normalization theory ?